# How much on average does it cost per month to go cycle touring in India?

Tags: touring

I am planning on going cycle touring and I was wondering if anyone can advise as to how much it will cost per month

Comment: When I did a short tour to France last year, my main expenses were accommodation, food and drink. In fact the only thing I can think of that didn't fall into this category was things like entrance to museums etc. Certainly shopping was out. But aren't you asking this question the wrong way around? I mean, I spent probably €150 per night on decent food and hotel. So, for me, a month would be getting on for €5000! But shouldn't budget drive accommodation, not the other way round?

Comment: Where? South America, Western Europe Eastern Europe - all have different pricing stuctures. Whats you tolerance for discomfort (camping under bridges vs 5 start hotels). Would you rather eat in a restaurant and sleep in a tent or sleep in a bed and eat tinned food.

Comment: It depends. From $5 to $500 or more a day I guess... I spend about $5-$20 a day in New Zealand and Australia depending on entry cost to museums etc. I spend more overseas if you factor in transport to and from the tour location. I suspect I'd spend more if I was somewhere I had to pay for accommodation or the entertainment was more expensive, most museums and galleries here are $10 or so per day for entry.

Comment: Tolerance for sleeping rough is high. Planning on cycling down through the states so north/ central/ south america.

Comment: so if accommodation costs are zero, doesn't your question just boil down to "how much per day does it cost to feed myself in north/central/south America?". You may have more joy with this on the travel stackexchange site, or maybe something like tripadvisor.